# Why does adding constexpr make VS2013 reject this?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2013, constexpr

This code does not compile in Visual Studio 2013

```
template <typename X> 
constexpr //error C2144: syntax error : 'bool' should be preceded by ';'
bool Test(X x)
{
    return true;
}
```

However, if I remove the `constexpr` keyword, it does compile.

But `constexpr` shouldn't be a problem? since it always returns true.

What went wrong?

Comment: Visual studio 2013 does not support `constexpr`. You need to upgrade to VS2017. See [Visual C++ Language Conformance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/visual-cpp-language-conformance).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the 2013 in the name, VS2013 does not purport to be a compiler targeting the C++11 standard (which was when `constexpr` was introduced).

The value of `__cplusplus` will be `201103L` for a C++11 compiler.

So your compiler encounters a token it does not recognise, and issues a diagnostic.